# libopencv_java3.so in qt pro file

Tags: android, c++, qt, opencv, android-ndk

I'm making an Android app in Qt and OpenCV.

It is working on desktop Linux, but fails on Android with this:

```
D/dalvikvm( 8059): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.myselfxyz.testapp-1/libTestApp.so 0x421b4f98
E/dalvikvm( 8059): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.myselfxyz.testapp-1/libTestApp.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1673): could not load library "libopencv_java3.so" needed by "libTestApp"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:771): library "libopencv_java3.so" not found
```

After deploying the app on my device, the file **libopencv_java3.so** is located next to **libTestApp.so** in **/data/app-lib/com.myselfxyz.testapp-1** directory, so I have no idea, why isn't it able to found it.

I'm using:

- Android NDK r10e
- OpenCV-android-sdk 3.1.0
- Qt kit: armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.5.1)
- My phone has Android version 4.2.2, but I don't think it matters.

My qt pro file looks like:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = TestApp

CONFIG += mobility c++11
MOBILITY += sensors

QT += qml quick widgets declarative sensors core multimedia

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    bridge.cpp \
    imageprocessor.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/include \
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/include/linux \

linux:!android {
    INCLUDEPATH += /opt/OpenCV/include/
    LIBS += -L/opt/OpenCV/build/lib \
        -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_videoio
}

android {
    QT += androidextras
    ANDROID_OPENCV = /opt/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native
    INCLUDEPATH += $$ANDROID_OPENCV/jni/include
    ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
    LIBS += -L$$ANDROID_OPENCV/libs/armeabi-v7a \
        -L$$PWD/android/libs/armeabi-v7a \
        -L$$OUT_PWD \
        -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect \
        -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab \
        -lopencv_java3
}

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

HEADERS += \
    bridge.h \
    imageprocessor.h

DISTFILES += \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/res/values/libs.xml \
    android/src/com/myselfxyz/testapp/JniExport.java \
    android/src/com/myselfxyz/testapp/TestApp.java

ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you already managed to run your application without opencv, so all the rest is set up accordingly.

Go to your project settings, and find the "Build steps".

There should be a step called **Build Android APK**. Click on **Details**. In the **Additional libraries** list, add `libopencv_java3.so`. It is usually in the `\sdk\native\libs\armeabi-v7a` folder.